# how to check enter is pressed and store characters which are in the character array

Tags: c

I want to check whether the word in the sentence is a number, floating number or a character.

**This is my code.**

```
gets(s);
while (s[c] != '\0')
{
    b[c]=s[c];

    if(s[c]==' '|| s[c]=='\n')
    {
        temp=0,temp1=0,temp2=0;

        for(i=j; i<=c; i++)
        {
            printf("%c",b[i]);
            j=i;
            if(b[i]=='.')
            {
                temp++;
            }
            else if(isdigit(b[i]))
            {
                temp1++;
            }
        }
        printf("===");
        if(temp1 >=0 && temp>0 )
        {
            printf(" It's a float number\n",b[j]);
            b[c]=NULL;
        }
        else if(temp==0&&temp1>0)
        {
            printf(" it's a number\n", b[j]);
            b[c]=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" it's a charecter\n",b[j],temp);
            b[c]=NULL;
        }
    }
    c++;
}
```

**from here,**

```
if(s[c]==' '|| s[c]=='\n')
{
    for(i=j; i<=c; i++)
    {
         printf("%c",b[i]);
         j=i;
    } 
}
```

**Description:**

I can print out the word before the space, but the last one of the sentences. How can I compare it?

Comment: First thing, update your resources. The `gets()` function was deprecated and should not be used anymore, even if it wasn't deprecated using it is dangerous.

Comment: Then what should I use? Instead of that

Comment: Thanks. I'm using `fgets()` and It's solved the problem